# Giving border-radius value to reveal component

Tags: javascript, html, css, reactjs

I m using reveal-highlight component and need to apply border-radius value.

In order to do that, i get canvas element and give border-radius value.

[image]

```
const el = document.getElementById(id);
      if (el) {
        const aa = el?.shadowRoot;
        const bb = aa?.childNodes[1];
        const canvas = bb?.childNodes[3] as HTMLElement;

        if (canvas && canvas.style) {
          
          canvas.style.borderBottomLeftRadius = borderBottomLeftRadius;
          
          canvas.style.borderBottomRightRadius = borderBottomRightRadius;
          
          canvas.style.borderTopLeftRadius = borderTopLeftRadius;
          
          canvas.style.borderTopRightRadius = borderTopRightRadius;
          
          canvas.style.borderRadius = borderRadius;
        }
      }
```

Its clipping the edge not really changing the radius when give border-radius to this canvas element.
like that:
[image: Corners are looks like clipped]

There is a small [demo](https://stackblitz.com/edit/react-zbnm7p?file=src%2FApp.js)

[image]

How i can give border-radius values to this reveal highlight ?

Comment: What are the values of `borderBottomLeftRadius`, `borderBottomRightRadius`, etc?

Comment: Let's say 10px.